# Can you get a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token for Firebase in PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, oauth

i am currently working on a Project with Firebase and i am trying to Implement the Firebase Cloud messaging service. I manage to make it work with a combination of PHP and Javascript (Javascript sends a Requiest to the server, where php makes a call to the Firebase API to send out a Notification).

The problem here is, that the code i use is for the old version, so its not using the HTTP v1.
When i looked at the docs on how to upgrade to the new version, i found out you need a short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token.

Thing is, the docs only show how you can get it via node.js, java, python, c# and go. 
So my question is, is there a way to get the short-lived OAuth 2.0 access token with php or do i have to use something like node.js for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your requirements, but if you want to send FCM notification from a PHP backend, I'd suggest checking out this (unofficial) [Admin SDK for PHP](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) (Disclaimer: I'm the creator of that library)

In its current state, you would need a Firebase Service Account (with Admin access) to be able to send notifications with it, but I'm currently working on a feature that will allow you to retrieve an OAuth access token for a given user (https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/pull/390) in case you really need this.

I'd like to invite you to join https://discord.gg/nbgVfty (the Discord-Community around the PHP Admin SDK) to discuss your use case and process further.

Even if the SDK is not for you, looking through the code might could give you some ideas...

An alternative could be to use the [Google PHP Api Client Services](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services) library, in which you can find a `FirebaseCloudMessaging` service.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the Links, really helped a lot. Got it working now ^^.
And the SDK will really help with other stuff i am working on.
And i will definitely join the Discord.